# pst-func linestyle is not showing

Tags: pstricks, pst-func

I plot an implicit function with pst-func. I choose **dotted** line style, but the output does not show what i expect.

Where is my mistake?

(By the way, I find only `dotted` and `dashed` options for line styles but i need more options.)

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=14pt,14pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pst-func} 

\def\tt{1}
\begin{document} 
\begin{psgraph}[Dx=1,Dy=1](0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2){4cm}{4cm}
    \psplotImp[algebraic,linestyle=dotted,linecolor=red,stepFactor=.3](-1.5,-1.5)(1.5,1.5)
    {(abs(x)+abs(y))-\tt}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: dotted line style is not possible for implicit defined functions. The reason is that the function is internally plotted as dots and the space between two dots cannot  really be controlled.

Answer (score 2):

Play around with the `stepFactor`

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=14pt,14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-func,pstricks-add}

\def\tt{1}
\begin{document}
\begin{psgraph}[Dx=1,Dy=1](0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2){4cm}{4cm}
    \psplotImp[algebraic,linestyle=dotted,linecolor=red,stepFactor=0.97](-1.5,-1.5)(1.5,1.5)
    {(abs(x)+abs(y))-\tt}
\end{psgraph}

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-2,-2)(2,2)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\pspolygon[linecolor=red,linestyle=dotted](0,-1)(1,0)(0,1)(-1,0)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

For that easy example I would recommend a `\pspolygon` see second picture.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, i need to plot different type of implicit functions which can not be expressed as simple segments.